# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 26, 38, 3) for Tensor 'ResizeBilinear:0', which has shape '(1, 299, 299, 3)'

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, imagenet

I tried the "object_detection" tutorial using inceptionv3 train pb file, but I am gettin gthe following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-1cfc370a11f2> in <module>()
  8   image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  9   # Actual detection.
---> 10   output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
 11   # Visualization of the results of a detection.
 12   vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(

<ipython-input-38-7704143af1b0> in run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph)
 33       # Run inference
 34       output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
---> 35                              feed_dict={ResizeBilinear: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})
 36 
 37       # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
893     try:
894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
896       if run_metadata:
897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, 
fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
1102                 'Cannot feed value of shape %r for Tensor %r, '
1103                 'which has shape %r'
-> 1104                 % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
1105           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
1106             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 26, 38, 3) for Tensor 'ResizeBilinear:0', which has shape '(1, 299, 299, 3)'
```

I thus tried to use the code below to resize the image:

```
 image = array(img).reshape(1, 299,299,3)
```

But the image still can't be passed to the `resizeBilinear` tensor.

I just changed this code:

```
#MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
#MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
#DOWNLOAD_BASE ='http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'
#upper code is origin model preparation 
PATH_TO_CKPT = /tmp/output_graph.pb
PATH_TO_LABELS = /tmp/output_labels.txt
NUM_CLASSES = 2
```

How can I fix this error?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that *Inception V3* is expecting an image input with a size of 299 x 299 pixels and 3 channels (color image.) Therefore it requires an input array of shape (1, 299, 299, 3).

You're trying to feed it a much smaller image with a size of 26 x 38 pixels. *Reshaping* is an array operation that rearranges the elements of the array along the dimensions, *without changing the number of elements*.

What you need is to *resize* the image once loaded to the required 299 x 299 pixels, with something like [`PIL.Image.resize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize), like this (untested):

```
image = array( img.resize( (299, 299) ) ).reshape(1, 299,299,3)
```

Nota bene, you still need to keep the reshape to add the extra dimension up front (you could also use expand_dims.)